# What is the libid of ACEDAO.dll?

Tags: mfc, ms-access-2007

I'm writing an MFC aplication and I need the **libid** of **ACEDAO.dll**.
How can I find it?

I found a key in my registry: {4AC9E1DA-5BAD-4AC7-86E3-24F4CDCECA28} Is this key universal?

Comment: I found a key in my registry:

{4AC9E1DA-5BAD-4AC7-86E3-24F4CDCECA28}

Is this key universal?

Comment: edit your question to add this information, it might be useful to people trying to answer you